# Auto Hot Key - can't interrupt a loop

Tags: autohotkey

Here is an example auto hot key script:

```
^j::
WinActivate, MyWindow
WinWaitActive, MyWindow

Loop
{
    If GetKeyState("Shift", "P") 
        Break  

    Click, 44, 55
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, 144, 155
    Sleep, 1000
}

return
```

Everything works fine but I can't interrupt the loop by pressig "Shift". What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to hold the Shift key for more than 2 seconds pressed, because of the sleep times.
Or try something like this:

```
^j::
Loop
{
    If !WinActive("MyWindow")
    {
        WinActivate, MyWindow
        WinWaitActive, MyWindow
    }
        Click, 44, 55
        Sleep_1000()
        Click, 144, 155
        Sleep_1000()
}
return

Sleep_1000(){
    Loop 10
    {
        Sleep, 100
        If GetKeyState("Shift", "P") 
            exit ; terminate the hotkey's thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a loop inside a hotkey definition is bad practice.
AHK doesn't provide true multithreading, so long running loops are generally a really bad idea.
Using a [timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.html) *fixes* this, and usage of a timer is anyway always what you want for something like this.
And it'll be much more simple as well.

So, with `Ctrl+j` we activate the desired window and create the timer and tell it to run our function `TimerCallback` (which we will shortly create) every 2secs:

```
^j::
    WinActivate, MyWindow
    WinWaitActive, MyWindow ;shouldn't be needed, but if you find it helpful, fair enough
    TimerCallback() ;run the function once, since the timer is going to
                    ;run it for the first time only after 2secs
    SetTimer, TimerCallback, 2000
return
```

And then we make shift be a hotkey for turning off the timer. And we for sure want to use the [`~` modifier](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) to not consume the key when the hotkey is fired:
`~Shift::SetTimer, koira, Off`

And now lets also define our function `TimerCallback`:

```
TimerCallback()
{
    Click, 44, 55
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, 144, 155
}
```

---

So here's again the script in full if something was somehow left unclear:

```
^j::
    WinActivate, MyWindow
    WinWaitActive, MyWindow ;shouldn't be needed, but if you find it helpful, fair enough
    TimerCallback() ;run the function once, since the timer is going to
                    ;run it for the first time only after 2secs
    SetTimer, TimerCallback, 2000
return

~Shift::SetTimer, TimerCallback, Off

TimerCallback()
{
    Click, 44, 55
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, 144, 155
}
```

Comment: It works, but I have checked an interval between mouse events in the program and it equals: ~1200 ms (Click, 44, 55 -> Click, 144, 155) and ~800ms. Why ?

Comment: Set [SetDefaultMouseSpeed](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetDefaultMouseSpeed.htm) at the top of your script to make your mouse move instantly. Also at worst Sleep could be inaccurate to up to like 20ms, read more about it [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm). Still not sure if this should account for that 200ms in both directions you're seeing. or maybe the default mousemove speed was just that much slower. Or maybe whatever program you're using to measure isn't that great.